# Load all images only after their display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show all Images only when images display in all in one pages html template.

this template [codingfeat.com/items/vr](http://codingfeat.com/items/vr)

i have many image on this page and i want load images after display for Decrease page loading time.

Comment: show us what you already tried

Comment: this template   http://codingfeat.com/items/vr/

Answer (score 0):

```
#css
img{ 
   display: none;
}
```

---

```
#JS
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').on('load', function(){
      $(this).fadeIn();
   }
}
```

Comment: tanks. but i have many image on this page. i want load images after display for Decrease page loading time. this code work this done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you worried about loading time, use CSS Sprite, remove etag, Optimize the image for web. Use CSS instead of images whenever possible. Cache your resource, use CDN, you can also try images less design like stackoverflow.com, you can do many more.

Comment: use only 20 products per page, rest load using lazy loading.